# Open the table by clicking on the name of the query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, recordset

I have the following logic that need to translate into VBA code:
1. User selects one or several query name(s) from a Combo box:
2. User clicks on "Show Table" button
3. Selected Table(s) is/are opened

So far, I have the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdShowTable_Click()
Dim valSelect1 As Variant
Dim strValue1 As String
Dim strValue2 As String
For Each valSelect1 In Me.Combo29.ItemsSelected
  DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)
  strValue1 = Me.Combo29.ItemData(valSelect1)
  strValue2 = "select TableName from [List of Queries] where QueryName = " ' & strValue1 & '" "
  DoCmd.OpenTable (strValue2)
  Me.Combo29.Selected(valSelect1) = False
  Next
  DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn)
  MsgBox "Complete!"  
end sub
```

I understand that mistake is at line strValue2. Syntax and logic is probably not correct as sql string is passed to the object but not executed. It has to be executed and then its value to be passed further to the Docmd.Open table command.

Please help to tie it all together!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can't decide on opening queries or tables ...

However, if each query holds a table name to open, go like this:

```
strValue1 = Me.Combo29.ItemData(valSelect1)
strValue2 = DLookup("TableName", "[List of Queries]", "QueryName = '" & strValue1 & "'")
DoCmd.OpenTable (strValue2)
```

If each query holds several table names, you'll have to open a recordset using the query as source, then loop the returned table names and open these.

Comment: it worked. Each query name corresponded to a table name. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: @ Gustav - I am trying to delete data first in the table that corresponds to the query that will update it first. When I built the database I mistakenly used Select Into instead of Insert Into Select. How do I make the following lines work - strValue = Me.Combo29.ItemData(valSelect)
        strValue3 = DLookup("TableName", "[List of Queries]", "QueryName = '" & strValue & "'")
        docmd.RunSQL (delete from '" & strValue3 & "")
        DoCmd.OpenQuery (strValue). I am getting error at docmd.Runsql command.

Comment: You need an SQL string to run: `DoCmd.RunSQL ("Delete From '" & strValue3 & "")`.

Comment: very much appreciate!